# Как определить какие именно два объекта с одинаковыми тегами столкнулись?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Есть объект на нем висит Rigidbody2D, CircleCollider2D, сам скрипт.
из него делается множество клонов (получается у всех имена - obgClon, тег - Ast)

хочется без тригера в солайдере, с помощью -

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ast")
        {
            Destroy(collision.gameObject, 0.5f);
        }
    }
```

понять какие именно объекты столкнулись и уничтожить их. А у меня выходит что уничтожаются все объекты разом.

Comment: Вместо тега можно сделать приведение или каст через GetComponent<T>(); Вход в коллизию срабатывает только у того кто вошёл в коллизию. Если уничтожатся все - значит вы что то не так делаете, убедитесь что ваши коллидеры не раздуты на всю карту... Не поверю что они просто так все разом вызывают OnCollisionEnter2D. Ну, ещё, в момент коллизии вам известно оба объекта, а вы уничтожаете только соседа. Не проще сразу обоих прихлопнуть? Destroy(collision.gameObject); Destroy(transforn.gameObject);

Comment: Ну, ещё как вариант - убедитесь что объекты расположены внутри нейтрального родителя. Ни в коем случае, не допускайте вложенностей вашего объекта в свою копию

Comment: @test123 колайдеры все по размеру и не раздуты. потому что если не обрабатывать событие 'OnCollisionEnter2D' то они летают и друг от друга спокойно отталкиваются. Добавил картинку с деспечером и клонами.

Comment: мне кажется что беда в том что у меня все объекты с одним тегом и именем. и при столкновении двух любых уничтожаются почему то все...

Comment: Имя и теги - это фигня, по большей части, необходимая для дизайнеров. Если вы грамотно писали код, имена и теги ни на что не могут влиять. У вас есть прямая ссылка от объекта попавшего в сферакаст, к чему вам вообще эти теги и имя? Есть ещё велосипедный вариант - самостоятельно сделать сферокаст, но, он не ответит на вопрос, что именно не правильно вы сделали.

Comment: Дайте название вашего скрипта/класса.

Comment: весь код я написал выше. он весит на прифабе объекта. потом при запуске игры создаются клоны, скриптом который весит на камере.Про сферокаст не понял... где взять прямую ссылку объектов столкнувшихся?

Comment: >>Про сферокаст не понял<< https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCast.html прямая ссылка содержится в RaycastHit и в Collision объекте

Answer (score 0):

Все... оказалась проблема в прифабах. у меня объект был на сцене, из него делались клоны. и при столкновении все убивалось. как только убрал со сцены и создавал клоны через прифабы все решилось.

Comment: серьезно?) Через 3 с половиной года решилось?)  Какое усердство

Comment: @AndrewStop_RU_war_in_UA да нет, вопрос задан 27 апр 2018 в 11:59, а ответ дан 27 апр 2018 в 14:05